# How to set android NDK path ?

Tags: android

```
15:41:40 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project Diggers ****
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "Cygwin GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
"C:\\NVPACK\\android-ndk-r8\\ndk-build.cmd" clean 
Cannot run program "C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd": Launching failed

Error: Program "C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;D:\and007\android-sdk-windows\androidndk;;D:\and007\eclipse;]

15:41:40 Build Finished (took 155ms)
```

Comment: please see this code and suggest to me what i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first set path to the project folder (the folder which contains  `jni` and `src` folders) then run the Android-ndk command like

```
cd path_to_the_your_project
```

Then run command which contain full path `ndl-build` file in Android-ndk folder
like this `/android-ndk-r8c/ndk-build`

Comment: please give me details because i cant set path.

Comment: to complex answer for a newbe :)